# Image not appearing in MvxImageView in android app

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross

I am using the MvxImageView in an android app to show the image in a MvxListView . I have saved the image in drawable folder inside Resources folder but the image does not appear in the list . I have done every permutation and combination as given here in the stackoverflow answers . This line works fine now but when these codes

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    local:MvxBind="ImageUrl 'res:icon1'"/>
```

Changes to :

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    local:MvxBind="ImageUrl Path "/>
```

Where Path is :

```
ttls.Add(new Title { title = f.Value, Path = "'res:icon1'" });
```

then no image is appearing .

Comment: try removing the single quotes?

Comment: @stuart In the output screen I am getting :  Failed to parse binding specification starting with ImageUrl Path . And I tried removing the single quotes, it did not work . Also when I give the URL in Path like : ttls.Add(new Title { title = f.Value, Path = "http://dummyimage.com/50X50/693269/fff.png&text=Hello.png" }); , then too it does not work . Tried reinstalling Downloadcache plugin and file plugin but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem you are facing is that `Path` is a reserved name - because of WPF heritage - so you can't use it in the binding expression like that...

If you really want to use `Path` as the property name, then this should work:

```
<Mvx.MvxImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    local:MvxBind="ImageUrl Path=Path "/>
```